# Parity mining on --chain dev for truffle migrate

Tags: mining, truffle, testnets, parity

I am using Parity to create a custom app and so I am using it locally on --dev.  "$ truffle migrate" fails, I think because there is no balance in the account.  It says:

```
Error: Insufficient funds. The account you tried to send transaction from does not
have enough funds. Required 471238800000000000 and got: 0.
```

But using --dev, this shouldn't be a problem, right?  The transactions should work without being mined first?  Or something like that?

I tried running genoil but (a) I don't think I need to on --dev and (b) it won't run on a VPS with no GPU anyway.

I tried attaching to Parity with geth attach and it connects (because eth.coinbase returns the correct address) but that user has 0 balance.  Also, miner.start() says:

```
ReferenceError: 'miner' is not defined
    at :1:1
```

I am invoking parity with:

`$ /path/to/parity --geth --chain dev --dapps-hosts="all" --dapps-apis-all --jsonrpc-hosts="all" --unlock 0x... --password DevUserPass.txt --author ...`

I have tried the "--author" flag with 0x as well, with the same result.

---

So I have a few related questions:

1 - What is your understanding of how the --chain dev option means you do NOT have to mine with parity?  The docs aren't really clear.

2 - If I do need to mine (like I use another testnet), how can I do that on a VPS?

3 - Is it possible that truffle needs to be told to use the --chain dev mining technique?  Like, it behaves different from a normal balance so has to be stated somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mine a `dev` chain on Parity because it does not run a Proof-of-Work engine. Instead, it runs `InstantSeal` which basically just creates a new block every 2 seconds if there are transactions available.

The `dev` chain is preloaded with an insane amount of development Ether. Just open your wallet, go to *Accounts*, click the *Add Account* button and then *Recovery* and then without entering anything, click *OK*.

You can also run with `--jsonrpc-api parity_accounts` and issue the following call in another terminal:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"parity_newAccountFromPhrase","params":["","password"],"id": 1}' localhost:8545
```

The trick is the account which can be recovered using an *empty recovery phrase* holds all the available tokens. This should be enough to get you started.

Read more on the configuration here: [Private-development-chain](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Private-development-chain); Read more on the engine here: [Consensus-Engines](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/wiki/Consensus-Engines)

Comment: Yes, this was what I needed.  The error is gone (and now I have a new error, but that is for a different thread.)  Thank you.

I hope you don't mind but I want to share two things for other people who need this answer:

1) the flag is -jsonrpc-apis

2) The other procedure is:

- open the UI (port 8180)
- Choose "Accounts"
- Choose "+ Account"
- Choose the Recovery Seed option
- Do NOT enter a seed.  Just hit "next" or whatever it is
- Finally click "Done" and you will have an account with lots of money.

Comment: I just got told that the dev chain accepts any block you find, so mining would work in theory, too.

Comment: Thank you.  But the issue here is that genoil won't work on a headless system (ie - no GPU) but otherwise I think you're 100% correct.